# Can ASIWebPageRequest download multilevels webpages with the sources internel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, asihttprequest

What I want is to implement an offline web browser that can save multi levels webpages, like save first level,save two levels.
Is ASIWebPageRequest satiable？
Thank you very much!